# Integrated Security

Tags: c#, remoting, windows-authentication

is there a managed code (without adding COM component or wrapped called to C++ routines) way to add integrated security to a C# Managed code assembly?

i.e. I want to write a client-server system where the server uses Remoting instead of IIS, but I want the client to automatically pass it's credentials to the server just like a browser does when communicating with an IIS server that has Integrated security enabled...

Can this be done? and if so, where is there some examples ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the Windows Login credentials?

Comment: No, I know how to do that... I want to know how to pass Integrated security credentials across the wire to a server in the same way that a browser does to an IIS web server... w/o actually passing the login and password... (I think a browser passes some coordinated token that the server can verify)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No - there is no pure managed interface to [SSPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380493(VS.85).aspx). But, there is an MSDN sample that [wraps SSPI for you](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973911.aspx), and then [uses the wrapper for remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973909.aspx).

Comment: Ah you freaken SAVIOUR!!!! The only thing I could find on the tubes was that there was a wrapper - not where it was! Thanks a million.

Comment: Is there a better answer in 2012?  We implemented a solution based on this sample (written in 2004 pre .net 2.0 ) and while it works it requires us to have a c++ project and depends on crt redist.  I see another answer below that says to use the NegotiateStream class but I don't see any examples.  Any tips?

Comment: @christopher - seems like MSDN has a sample using NegotiateStream. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.negotiatestream.aspx

Comment: I saw that but couldn't see how to make it work for my situation.  I'm using the VSphere SDK for .NET which has a sessionmanager class with a LoginBySSPI method that takes a Base64 encoded SSPI token as an argument.  I couldn't figure out how to use NegotiateStream to get me there.  If you have a thought on that I could post a new question for you to ansewr.

Answer (score 2):

.NET 2 has NegotiateStream which is used by TCP remoting to provide SSPI.

Comment: Can you provide a small sample of how to use this class?

Answer (score 1):

there is WCF and all .net libraries for you to implement something like that. I used something like this

http://www.theproblemsolver.nl/usingthemembershipproviderinwinforms.htm

and for the server part

http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2007/02/03/video-creating-a-service-with-windows-communication-service-wcf.aspx

those two steps nice to start a own implemented security integration.

Answer (score -1):

When you say "remoting instead of IIS," what exactly do you mean? A remoting endpoint (the server end) is typically hosted in IIS since this gives you lots of stuff for free, like authentication, scaling through load balancing - especially for singlecall type objects - that is to say, you don't want to keep state for successive calls to the endpoint.

You can host a remoting endpoint using the http stack in a client app also in xp/sp2 and beyond utilising the http.sys driver directly (which is handleded automatically for you btw).

Regardless, for automatic logon with NTLM credentials, I suggest you host remoting in IIS, and use System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials for the client's credentials your client app. This will pass the context credentials to the server app, presuming the current security zone (intranet/internet/trusted/etc) allows it.

-Oisin

Comment: I mean without using IIS... Using tcp/ip channels instead,  using System.Runtime.Remoting and System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp:

RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType( );

Comment: Cause I want to use tcp binary protocol - don't want to incur the restrictions imposed by IIS to get the free stuff, 
... that's exactly my question... How do I do this (authentication myself?